# Compiling Python with Checkinstall

Tags: python, linux, compilation, debian

I am running checkinstall to compile Python on debian.

I experienced a bunch of errors before this that would cause it to fail due to not being able to create a directory. At that point, I would just mkdir it myself and it would get past this point. But now I get this error:

```
    copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.5/_elementtree.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so -> /usr/local/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
    Makefile:1458: recipe for target 'sharedinstall' failed
```

Does anyone know of anything I might be doing wrong with checkinstall?

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: You have the directory error you need to change the directory **sharedinsstal cant find your directory**
you can visit this link [enter link description here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/53871/debian-checkinstall-ignores-install-no-how-to-have-it-build-but-not-autoinstal)

Comment: @summ Can you clarify how your link can help us?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seemed to work for me:

1. Use the -n flag on `make` for your target
2. pipe to shell script
3. run `checkinstall` with that shell script

I ran the following commands:

```
$ make -n altinstall > altinstall_script.sh
$ chmod +x altinstall_script.sh
$ sudo checkinstall ./altinstall_script.sh
```